# Return multiple modes in python as float values

Tags: python, statistics, mode

Im struggling with the code below.
The output is a list of float values. Is there an easy way to get just the float values without returning a list. 
So for mode(x) instead of  --> [2.0, 22.0, 85.0] just 2.0, 22.0, 85.0

```
x=[2,10,20,22,22,85,50,60,80,85,2,100]

def mode(x):
    largestCount = 0
    modes = []
    for i in x:
        if i in modes:
            continue
        count = x.count(i)
        if count > largestCount:
            del modes[:]
            modes.append(i)
            largestCount = count
        elif count == largestCount:
            modes.append(i)
    return [float(i) for i in modes]
```

Comment: What's wrong with returning a list? Since the number of floats returned by this function is based on `modes`, a list of a variable size, it's best for the function to return a list. Returning a tuple instead makes little sense since a tuple is meant for a sequence of a fixed size.

Comment: for what purpose would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

A Python function cannot return three values. What you think is three values is actually one *tuple* of three elements. Convert the result to a tuple before returning:

```
return tuple(float(i) for i in modes)
```